# wordpress meta value compare between two date

Tags: meta-query, user-meta, date

I want to check date between two year of birth. But my saved value is date of birth. Meta key "birth_date".
Now I want to check value between years using year.
My saved date format  like "01/01/1995"

Here I applied below code to fetch value.

```
$studentdata = get_users(
                array(
                    'meta_query'=> array(
                                       array(
                                          'key' => 'birth_date',
                                          'value'   => array(
                                               '01/01/'.$startyear,'31/12/'.$endyear),
                                          'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                        )
                                    ),
                    'role'=>'student'
                )
            );  
print_r($studentdata);
```

Comment: You need to save your `birth_date` in this format: `YYYY-MM-DD` - [See Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Thanks for your comment. Then can you suggest me what will be my meta query?

Comment: The meta_query seems fine but the format in **how you're saving your data** is incorrect. You need to save it as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I used " value'   => array( '01/01/'.$startyear,'31/12/'.$endyear), is that ok with that format?  I already saved many date in database.

Comment: It seems you do not want to understand, you **CANNOT** sort by date if it is not **`YYYY-mm-dd`** or unix timestamp. Change your format, else, sorry for you, then you are born to struggle with something you will not solve

Comment: @PieterGoosen Ok thanks. I solved. the query have to change little bit after save with that format u suggested. I was confused there so I asked.  'value'   => array( $startyear'-01-01',$endyear'-12-31'), Why down voted?

Comment: @LemonKazi You can add an answer with your solution so it's here for others to see later :) After a couple of days you will be able to accept your answer too

Answer (score 1):

After some research on wp codex I found my solution. Here I have to change birth_date format during save.
I saved value like `yy-mm-dd` this format and changed my `meta_query`

Here is the code

```
    $studentdata = get_users(
                array(
                    'meta_query'=> array(
                                       array(
                                          'key' => 'birth_date',
                                          'value'   => array(
                                               $startyear.'-01-01',$endyear.'-12-31'),
                                          'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                        )
                                    ),
                    'role'=>'student'
                )
            );  
print_r($studentdata);
```